# Native Facebook login and Azure AD B2C using MSAL

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to build a setup where my Xamarin forms app authenticates with Facebook, and when done gets a token from the Azure AD B2C to use when requesting data from my API.

So far I have native Facebook login up and running, meaning no web UI login, but uses the user's Facebook app and I get a the Facebook access token. This is the one I want to use when requesting a token from the Azure AD B2C

**My issue now is** how I should integrate this with Azure AD B2C. **I want the API to be protected using Azure AD B2C and that part is enabled too, but I need the App to request a token before it can access my API.** This is the part where I'm not sure if it is possible yet, with out letting the Azure AD popup with some UI.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, **Azure AD B2C does not support acknowledging authentication that occurred outside of B2C.**

You should request either support for the Facebook SDK and/or more broadly, supporting swapping tokens obtained outside of B2C for B2C tokens via the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv)